# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'customer'

Tags: python

```
customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(pk=4)
ipdb> SimilarCustomerFinder(self, customer=customer, fields=self.fields)
*** TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'customer'
```

In `SimilarCustomerFinder` class, I have

```
def __init__(self, customer, fields):
    self._matches = {}
    props = self.__class__.__dict__.keys()
    self.customer = customer
    self.fields = fields
    self.checks = [k for k in props if k.startswith('check_')]
    if customer:
        self.user_id = customer.user.pk
    else:
        self.user_id = -1

    for check in self.checks:
        c = check.replace('+', '_')
        getattr(self, c)()
```

I am struggling with this error. How could I fix it? If I remove `customer=customer`, I got `*** AttributeError: 'CustomerUpdateForm' object has no attribute 'user'`, why?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. What is `self` in that first snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the `ipdb` output it seems like you're trying to create an instance using this command:

```
SimilarCustomerFinder(self, customer=customer, fields=self.fields)
```

However `self` is an implicitly passed argument so you shouldn't pass it in explicitly. Like this:

```
SimilarCustomerFinder(customer=customer, fields=self.fields)
```

Or if you really intended to pass it in explicitly (which would be really weird and probably doesn't do what you intend - but who knows ...) you have to call the method explicitly on the class:

```
SimilarCustomerFinder.__init__(self, customer=customer, fields=self.fields)
```